# Contact form not sending email after content verification

Tags: php, forms, email

I have a contact form that links to another `.php` document to use as validation (to ensure that all the fields are filled in etc) but upon submission and a success notification, an email never arrives.

Here is `contact.php` :

```
<?php include("header.php"); ?>

<form name="contactform" method="post" action="send_form_email.php">

<table width="450px">

<tr>

 <td valign="top">

  <label for="first_name">First Name *</label>

 </td>

 <td valign="top">

  <input  type="text" name="first_name" maxlength="50" size="30">

 </td>

</tr>

<tr>

 <td valign="top">

  <label for="last_name">Last Name *</label>

 </td>

 <td valign="top">

  <input  type="text" name="last_name" maxlength="50" size="30">

 </td>

</tr>

<tr>

 <td valign="top">

  <label for="email">Email Address *</label>

 </td>

 <td valign="top">

  <input  type="text" name="email" maxlength="80" size="30">

 </td>

</tr>

<tr>

 <td valign="top">

  <label for="telephone">Telephone Number</label>

 </td>

 <td valign="top">

  <input  type="text" name="telephone" maxlength="30" size="30">

 </td>

</tr>

<tr>

 <td valign="top">

  <label for="comments">Message *</label>

 </td>

 <td valign="top">

  <textarea  name="comments" maxlength="1000" cols="25" rows="6"></textarea>

 </td>

</tr>

<tr>

 <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center">

  <input type="submit" value="Submit"> 

 </td>

</tr>

</table>

</form>

<?php include("footer.php"); ?>
```

And here is `send_form_email.php` -

```
<?php include("header.php"); ?>

<?php

if(isset($_POST['email'])) {



    // EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED

    $email_to = "rob.jeffrey@redchevron.co.uk";

    $email_subject = "Contact Form Submission";





    function died($error) {

        // your error code can go here

        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";

        echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";

        echo $error."<br /><br />";

        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";

        die();

    }



    // validation expected data exists

    if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||

        !isset($_POST['last_name']) ||

        !isset($_POST['email']) ||

        !isset($_POST['telephone']) ||

        !isset($_POST['comments'])) {

        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       

    }



    $first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required

    $last_name = $_POST['last_name']; // required

    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required

    $telephone = $_POST['telephone']; // not required

    $comments = $_POST['comments']; // required



    $error_message = "";

    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';

  if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {

    $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';

  }

    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";

  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {

    $error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';

  }

  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$last_name)) {

    $error_message .= 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';

  }

  if(strlen($comments) < 2) {

    $error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';

  }

  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {

    died($error_message);

  }

    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";



    function clean_string($string) {

      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");

      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);

    }



    $email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";

    $email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";

    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";

    $email_message .= "Telephone: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";

    $email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";





// create email headers

$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".

'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .

'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  

?>



<!-- include your own success html here -->



Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.



<?php

}

?>

<?php include("footer.php"); ?>
```

I am not sure if any additional code is needed to tell the form where it will actually be sent from. Any explanation would be very helpful as I am a novice.

Comment: Is this all of your code from send_form_email.php?

Comment: Try it again but take the `@` away from `@mail()`. Then you should see an error, and you can include it in your question.

Comment: Aside from the code within the php includes, yes. I'm assuming I'm missing something huge?

Comment: did you see any error, plz share that

Comment: taking the @ out fixed the issue :D thanks willoller. could you submit that as an answer so I can mark it as correct? Thanks

Comment: That is not possible. @ simply tells PHP not to output warning messages. You must have changed something else in the mean time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it again but take the @ away from @mail(). Then you should see an error, and you can include it in your question.